# Nested anonymus functions

Tags: php

I'm trying to write some nested PHP anonymus functions, the structure is the one that you see below and my question is: how can I make it work without errors?

```
$abc = function($code){

    $function_A = function($code){
        return $code;
    };

    $function_B = function($code){
        global $function_A;
        $text = $function_A($code);
        return $text;
    };

    $function_B($code);

};

echo $abc('abc');
```

The output is **Fatal error: Function name must be a string** in this line:

```
$text = $function_A($code);
```

This message does not say anything to me :(

Comment: `$function_A` is not defined in global scope.

Comment: `$function_A` gets defined in the local variable scope of the outer function, not as global. See also [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576)

Answer (score 10):

The thing here is that your `$function_A` is not defined in the global scope, but in the scope of `$abc`. If you want you can try using `use` in order to pass your `$function_A` to the scope of your `$function_B`:

```
$abc = function($code){

    $function_A = function($code){
        return $code;
    };

    $function_B = function($code) use ($function_A){
        $text = $function_A($code);
        return $text;
    };

    $function_B($code);

};
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, to pass variables other than `$this` and superglobals into an anonymous closure you have to use the `use` statement.

```
<?php

$abc = function($code){

    $function_A = function($code){
        return "Code: {$code}";
    };

    $function_B = function($code) use ($function_A) {
        $text = $function_A($code);
        return $text;
    };

    return $function_B($code);
};

echo $abc('abc');
```

Here's a working example: http://3v4l.org/u1CtZ